# Troubles with a math formula - Java

Tags: java, eclipse, math

I'm making a program for my java class that calculates the population for a year given the start year (2011) and increases the population by 1.2% every year. The population for 2011 is 7.000 (I'm using decimals, instead of billions). I currently have this code.

```
int startYear = 2011;
int endYear = user_input.nextInt();
double t = 1.2; //Population percent increase anually
double nbr = (endYear - startYear); //Number of years increased
double pStart = 7.000; //Starting population of 2011
double pEnd = pStart * Math.exp(nbr * t); // Ending population of user input
DecimalFormat nf = new DecimalFormat("2");
System.out.println("Population in " + endYear + ": " (nf.format(pEnd)));
```

There's no errors in the code, everything works, but I'm having troubles with the pEnd equation. Currently when I enter 2016 for the end year, i get 22824. I've tried googling a formula, but i can't find anything. Do any of you guys have an idea of the formula? If you enter 2016 for the end year, it should be around 7.433

Comment: what is your formula in plain math?? is it pStart x e^(nbr x t)?

Comment: `exp(double a): Returns Euler's number e raised to the power of a double value.` are you sure this is what you want?

Comment: Im not sure i understand the formula, but this is the one i was given

http://i.imgur.com/t5B8Ube.png

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `Math.pow(1 + t / 100, nbr)` instead of `Math.exp(nbr * t)`  because you need `(1+t/100)^nbr` (i.e. multiply `1 + t / 100` on itself `nbr` times), not `exp^(nbr*t)`:

```
double pEnd = pStart * Math.pow(1 + t / 100, nbr); // Ending population of user input
```

Comment: It gives me 248 when i put that in, am i missing something else?

Comment: @MemeBoi, yes, I added to my answer

Comment: Yep, need to wait 2 mins to do that

Comment: There is no problem with using Math.exp per se - the problem is with the value of the rate (1.2 vs 0.012).

Comment: @assylias, why? He needs to pow the ratio (1.012). To use `exp` he needs to get `ln` of the ratio.

Comment: @PhilipVoronov The exponential form is generally used for continuous compounding whereas the power form is used for discrete compounding. In the example, continuous compounding makes more sense. Also note that exp(nbrt*t) and (1+t)^nbr are approximately equal for small values of t.

Answer (score 2):

You're incrementing by a factor of 1.2, which would represent 120% instead of 1.2%. I think what you want is :

```
double t = 0.012;
```

This change gives me an exact value of 7.4328558258175175 from 2011 to 2016.

EDIT : here's the code as requested by the author :

```
public static void main(String args[]){
    int startYear = 2011;
    int endYear = 2016;
    double t = 0.012; //Population percent increase anually
    double nbr = (endYear - startYear); //Number of years increased
    double pStart = 7.000; //Starting population of 2011
    double pEnd = pStart * Math.exp(nbr * t); // Ending population of user input
    System.out.println("Population in " + endYear + ": " + pEnd);
}
```

Comment: For some reason i'm getting 7.136506736265682 when i enter 2016, everything seems right so i'm not sure why. Can i see your code?

Comment: Thanks! Not sure what went wrong with mine since it was they were the same, but when i copied yours it worked.

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

```
double pEnd = pStart * Math.pow(1.0 + t / 100, nbr);
```